# House on wedding ring, why not?

Tags: halacha, minhag, wedding, jewelry, kiddushin-eirusin

It seems in the past at least for Ashkenazim the wedding rings had houses on them (some of them had a hinge on the roof so that the house opened, from the top)
[image].
See.
https://www.pinterest.com/kerrydallas/judaica-house-rings/
  http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=53281&pgnum=36
http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=53281&pgnum=38
[https://www.google.com/search?q=טבעת+קידושין&prmd=ivn&source=lnms&tbm=isch](https://www.google.com/search?q=%D7%98%D7%91%D7%A2%D7%AA+%D7%A7%D7%99%D7%93%D7%95%D7%A9%D7%99%D7%9F&prmd=ivn&source=lnms&tbm=isch)

But it seems not to be used anymore.
Are there Any halacha or Torah Sources that speak about this type of ring?

I understand that there is [halacha E"H 31.2](https://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh,_Even_HaEzer.31.2) about no stones but most of the houses do not have stones

(Does anyone know what the hinge was for?)

Comment: are you asking whether such rings are proper, or for any mention at all in literature?

Comment: Peter and Ruth Gays' book on German Jewry discusses how such a ring (usually owned by the kehilloh) would be used at a wedding, but a simple band would be worn afterward. I don't see how the schul's ring could be used, since it would need to be returned.

Comment: I thought the reason for the minhag not to have stones was because of their unclear value, so there's a concern she'll over estimate it's worth. I don't see why a ring with a house on it would be any more clear. She might think it's a super fancy ring

Comment: @mevaqesh both 15 15

Comment: @robev nice idea, but is not the conclusion of that halacha that  her face is covered, and we claim it is worth a pruta (so practically anything is ok?) (And why she sill not overestimate a  wedding band, especialy know when there is so much ignerince)

Comment: @hazoriz I don't know about you but my community is noheg both: no stones and cover her face

Comment: @NoachMiFrankfurt "I don't see how the schul's ring could be used, since it would need to be returned". There's some nuance in that statement that I'm missing. As I understand it, the ring does need to be owned at the time of *nissuin*. Why couldn't the groom buy the ring from the shul and then sell it back after nissuin is finished?

Comment: @DanF just to be technical after the nissuin it is the bride who sells it

Comment: @robev aruch hashulchan brings your idea in the end it 31.8 http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14243&pgnum=216 , but if not stones it is not a big mistake

Comment: The title asks "why not" the post just asks for sources about it. Try to decide what you are asking, and clarify it in the post.

Comment: @NoachMiFrankfurt That book you mentioned (_The Jews of Germany_) is a great resource and a great read. :)

Comment: @ezra, glad to hear it. My father ש"י bought it for grandfather ז"ל as a gift, considering our heritage (I believe that there's a photo of his childhood schul somewhere in there)

Answer (score 1):

Possibly because it has an engraving/etching, and would have the same problem as one - that she might think that she is being mekudeshes with the value of said engraving, and it is not be'etzem worth a prutah

Source for problem with etching: .שלחן העזר חלק ב, דף מ

Comment: see https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/18497/wedding-ring-composition