# Can a wedding band be made from white gold?

Tags: halacha, wedding, jewelry, kiddushin-eirusin

Is there any reason why a wedding ring for a woman should not be made from white gold? No gems, no in-carvings of course. I am interested in orthodox views.

Comment: afaik what matters is a minimum (discernible) value. That value is more than satisfied by any gold.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Wedding ring composition](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/18497/wedding-ring-composition)

Comment: Similar to others who commented here, my wife also wanted a white gold ring. I asked my Mesader Kidushin, and he said it's perfectly fine.

Comment: My wife received a white gold ring. I am Chassidish and I always only saw white gold rings at weddings.

Comment: Thank you all. @DanF All women in my community wear yellow gold rings, I don't like it, my future husband either, so we wanted to know is there any prohibition or ruling ...

Comment: Ana - I wish you and your future husband numerous years of a happy loving lasting marriage and a gratifying family life and future. With that in mind, all you and your husband need is something *shaveh prutah* ("worth a penny"). I've seen numerous pre-marriage couples fight over trivialities such as the ring, as well as other nonsense. How foolish to argue on this before marriage. If only they could perceive the inevitable bigger problems that come during marriage that they need to deal with! I also challenge you to be unique in this area. You don't need to follow your community!

Comment: White gold is the standard practice in Yeshivish circles.

Answer (score 1):

There is no issue in a white gold wedding bad provided that

- it is the groom's own possession
- it is worth at least a *pruta* ([a few cents today](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/5685/11501)) and
- that the bride is clear on what it is (see [SA EH 31:1](https://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Even_HaEzer.31.1?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en)).

The custom I know is to have it pure gold and totally unadorned but [chabad.org](https://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/476748/jewish/Halachic-Requirements-for-the-Wedding-Band.htm) mentions that, in certain circles, it is customary to use a silver ring.

See [here](https://www.yeshiva.co/midrash/shiur.asp?id=19568) under 6 for further reading and [here](https://www.businesshalacha.com/en/newsletter/silver-wedding) if you are interested in the halachic arguments when the ring is not what it was thought to be - it is interesting but not relevant to your question in practice.